# Need to send CPU and Memory information to Excel sheet

Tags: excel, powershell

I am automating health check for some of the windows servers. I am very new to PowerShell (started today).

I want the CPU and Memory utilization of a windows server at an instant to be recorded in an Excel workbook in different sheets. After googling and following the documents, I have found the commands to retrieve this data using Win32_processor and win32_operatingsystem classes.

I am using Export-CSV cmdlet which directly copies the output to the excel.

I am using New-Object cmdlet and created a psobject to get both the outputs added to the property and then pasted in excel.

```bsh
$Memory = gwmi win32_operatingsystem | Select-Object @{Name = "MemoryUsage"; Expression = {"{0:N2}" -f ((($_.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $_.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $_.TotalVisibleMemorySize) }}
$CPU = gwmi win32_processor | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average
$Props = @{"Memory"= $Memory ; "CPU Utilization" = $CPU}
$Mydata = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $Props
$MYdata | Export-Csv C:\Users\Mitu\Desktop\output-excel.csv -nti
```

Any other way to get this things done?

Also, I want to send this csv to our email id. What things are required to achieve this via powershell?

Comment: Excel and csv are very different things.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the best way to do something like this is the one that gives you a fair result, quickly, without a massive load on the system.

Having said that, there's a few things I'm not sure I understand. This is a point in time snapshot of total free RAM and CPU utilization over the last second- I'm not sure that data is going to be particularly useful. Even firing up a few tabs of Chrome could drastically change it.

When one of our techs wanted something similar today (Some servers went out with misconfigured NICs) I helped him write a very similar script- except he fed it a list of 450 machine and it did the WMI Query remotely. I also like to use [Get-WmiObject](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wmi/2010/01/06/wmic-vs-wmi-powershell-cmdlets/).

Lastly, I don't personally care for the idea of emailing this data- someone is going to have to read all those emails, and take action. I'd rather write it to an SQL Database, or at very least log it to a CSV on a file share.

Having said all that- Feed this a list of computer names, and update the last line with the email addresses and SMTP Server, and run it with an account that has rights to the remote machines (… and rights to send email on your server), and it should run the WMI Queries on all the machines, throw the results in a single CSV file, and mail it to you.

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path "ListOfcomputers.txt"

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $Memory = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $computer| Select-Object @{Name = "MemoryUsage"; Expression = {"{0:N2}" -f ((($_.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $_.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $_.TotalVisibleMemorySize) }}
    $CPU = Get-WmiObject win32_processor |  Select-Object -property LoadPercentage 
    $Props = @{"Memory"= $Memory.MemoryUsage ; "CPU Utilization" = $CPU.LoadPercentage}
    $Mydata = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $Props
    $MyData
    $MYdata | Export-Csv "output-excel.csv" -Append 
}

Send-MailMessage -From 'Script <Script@Example.com>' -To 'User <user@Example.com>', 'User 2 <user2@Example.com>' -Subject 'Sending the Report' -Body "Here's the report" -Attachments "output-excel.csv" -SmtpServer 'smtp.example.com'
```